# C++ Constructor that accepts const reference to abstract class can't initialize std::map

Tags: c++

I have an abstract class A which is defining an interface for it's implementation in class B. All methods of A are pure virtual.

My problem is with the constructor of B with signature B(const A &base). I'm stuck... I cannot figure out to properly copy the contents of the std::map. See below for more details. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
struct W {
    W() = default;
};

template<typename T>
struct V : public W {
    V() = default;
};

class A {
public:
    A() = default;
    virtual std::map<std::shared_ptr<const W>, std::any> getFields() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class B : public A {
private:
    std::map<std::shared_ptr<const V<T>>, std::any> _fields;
    T _value;

public:

    B(T value) : _value(value) {
    }

    explicit B(const A &base) {
        for (std::pair<std::shared_ptr<const W>, std::any> field : base.getFields()) {
            auto key = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<const V<T>>(field.first);
            // the line below does not compile...
            _fields.insert(key, field.second);
        }  
    }

    std::map<std::shared_ptr<const W>, std::any> getFields() const override {
        std::map<std::shared_ptr<const W>, std::any> copy;
        copy.insert(_fields.begin(), _fields.end());
        return copy;
    }
};

struct C {
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const B<int>>> vec;

  void addElement(const A& element) {
      vec.push_back(std::make_shared<const B<int>>(element));
  }  
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::map::insert()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) takes a key-value pair, not separate key and value:

```
_fields.insert(std::make_pair(key, field.second));
```

Alternatively, consider [std::map::emplace()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace), which constructs the key-value pair in place inside the map:

```
_fields.emplace(std::move(key), std::move(field.second));
```